# "Input Submit" Cross-browser compatibility

Tags: css, input, cross-browser

```
<input type="submit" value="Share" />
```

In Chrome/Safari:

http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/619/btnwebkit.png

In FF:

http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/347/btnff.png

Can someone please tell me why they don't look the same?

Even, when I set the font-size, font-family, padding and margin, the button in FF will always look bigger than the one in Chrome/Safari.

Comment: Mmm... One more thing to reset that comes to mind is `line-height`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because default styles on HTML elements like input buttons and H1 and UL and LI and so forth are subject to the browser developer's whim. You can minimize the disruption by using a reset stylesheet. That said,  you may get better results by using `<button type="submit" value="Share">Share</button>` instead of an input (with a type of button), and setting the styles on that.

Comment: Yes, I stopped using input 10 years ago. Use button and code up your own functionality :)